# pg_close when using persistent postgres connections?

Tags: php, postgresql, persistent-connection

when using pg_pconnect connections to connect from php to postgres, does pg_close :

1. really close the connection (ruining the persistent effect) ?
2. hand over the connection to the pconnect pool ?

Comment: This should be documented, have you checked the docs or are you just asking?

Comment: I checked the docs on http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-close.php which does not clearly make its point (except for a comment that i wanted to double check on stack overflow). But you are right I missed http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-pconnect.php : "the pg_close() will not close persistent links generated by pg_pconnect()." I'll close the question

Comment: Don't close, add that as an answer instead. I was just asking for feedback, so if you found the answer, add it below. You can accept it later on as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has to do with the PHP.ini configuration, if the label **[pgsql.allow_persistent](http://php.net/manual/en/pgsql.configuration.php)** is set to true then pg_close will not close the connection because it is persistent, otherwise if you set it to false pg_close will close the connection.

The documentation states on [pg-pconnect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-pconnect.php):

```
pg_close() will not close persistent links generated by pg_pconnect()
```